# Trace a process on a Linux box

Tags: linux, ftp

I've noticed that one system user is constantly downloading a single JPEG file (every few seconds) via FTP server. The source IP is actually assigned to the server itself. I've tried to use tools like lsof, ps, top. I've also checked the cron jobs with no luck. Could you please advise how I can trace the source of this process, script? Please note that this server is running cPanel.

I could use strace however the process is not running long enough to catch it.

```
# tail /var/log/xferlog
    Wed Jan 23 14:21:26 2013 0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 14558 /path_to_dir/file.jpg b _ o r user ftp 1 * c
    Wed Jan 23 14:21:26 2013 0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 14558 /path_to_dir/file.jpg b _ o r user ftp 1 * c
    Wed Jan 23 14:21:27 2013 0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 14558 /path_to_dir/file.jpg b _ o r user ftp 1 * c
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could temporarily replace that file with a much larger file, or a FIFO (see `mkfifo` command) and then look for that process again.

Comment: this is a great idea that I never thought of. perhaps a symlink to /dev/random would work if pureftpd follows symlinks. Then it will be held indefinitely. You would of course need to kill the process fairly quickly or you might run out of memory.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-f` option of `strace` for tracing child processes. Get  pid of suspicious process, then execute `strace -f -p pid -o /tmp/strace.log`. You should search "connect"  or "RETR" keyword.